# apple developer account membership under 18

Tags: ios, membership

I'm 17 and I want to start publishing and using the benefits that comes with the Developer Program Membership. In the legal agreement says that I should be over 18, and I'm not so, i can't do it. I know one solution is use a account in my father's name. But I have one question.

- In the future, when I'm 18, this account membership can be transferred to my Apple ID without pay in 99 dollars and don't lose the 15% plus Revenue After One Year (85%) or I need in my Apple ID pay another 99 dollars to get membership statute (switch the app for this account) and wait more one year to have 85% Revenue After One ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen to me when I was going to get an Apple Developer Membership. Because I was not 18, the account had to go under my parent's name. We then proceeded to speak with somebody from Apple on the phone to ask the same question you are asking. She told us that when you are 18, the account can be cloned to another email address with your name and your parents account will be removed.

**TL/DR**

When you're 18, you can transfer the account to your one with your email and name.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions. I appreciate.

Comment: No problem. Enjoy creating iOS apps!